# numpy.savetxt() -- tuple index out of range when writing string to text file

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write two strings into a .txt file using numpy.savetxt(). I want the strings to be on consecutive lines. However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
ncol = X.shape[1]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Which occurs at the first line I call np.savetxt(). My code is below:

```
import numpy as np

data=np.loadtxt('data.txt')
name1 = 'James'
name2 = 'James 2'

hi = 'Hello {}'.format(name1)
bye  = 'Goodbye {}'.format(name2)

np.savetxt('greet.txt', hi, fmt="%s", newline='\n')
np.savetxt('greet.txt', bye, fmt="%s")
```

I've tried it without fmt, changing '%s' to other things, but they all give me the same error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `hi` and `bye` should be array types. Any reason why you want to use `np.savetxt` in particular?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Changing hi and bye to array types fixed the problem, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the @moses-koledoye comment and @jvnna's answer, the following is the correct answer.

The `hi` and `bye` variables are of type `string`

```
hi = 'Hello {}'.format(name1)
bye  = 'Goodbye {}'.format(name2)
```

You are trying to save them to a txt file with the numpy function `np.savetxt`, according to the documentation:

> Save an array to a text file.

So the `hi` and `bye` variables **must** be of type `np.array` in order to be handled with that function. Also, some reshape is needed.

A snippet code that does the trick could be:

```
hi = 'Hello {}'.format(name1)
bye  = 'Goodbye {}'.format(name2)

hi = np.array(hi).reshape(1, )  # This does the trick for hi
bye  = np.array(bye).reshape(1, ) # This does the trick for bye

np.savetxt('greet.txt', hi, fmt="%s", newline='\n')
np.savetxt('greet.txt', bye, fmt="%s")
```